# fpdf printing strings instead of value

Tags: php, jquery, html, pdf, fpdf

What happens here is I want to print `cat1`'s value instead of that `cat1` literally is being saved in the pdf. I know it must be simple error. But help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
require('WriteHTML.php');
extract($_REQUEST);

$pdf = new PDF_HTML();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 15);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 14);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 7); 
for ($i = 1; $i <= $noofitems; $i++) {
  $htmlTable='<TABLE>
                <TR>
                  <TD>Item Category:</TD>
                  <TD>cat'.$i.'</TD>
                  <TD>Item Name:</TD>
                  <TD>item'.$i.'</TD>
                </TR>
              </TABLE>';
  $pdf->WriteHTML2("$htmlTable");
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 6);
}
$pdf->Output(); 
?>
```

Comment: your `$noofitmes` not set a value before so the looping is working just once.<br> from your code, you're not setting the value of cat1 put as the string but you put cat and you concat (.) with the `$i` variable which it's value is 1, so what value of that you're expected?

Answer (score 0):

So is cat1 a variable?

```
$cat1
```

If so, then change

```
<TD>cat'.$i.'</TD>
```

to

```
<TD>'.$cat{$i}.'</TD>
```

Comment: The returned values are empty.

Comment: Yes cat1,cat2,cat3.....catn are variables and trying to save them in a pdf using fpdf

Comment: Are you certain that $cat1 is set? As this should work so long as $cat1 is already set by the time you define $htmlTable.

Comment: If not, try; ${"cat".$i}

Comment: $cat1 is being got from another php page and i am extract the value here.

Comment: When I try your second solution I get unexpected $ error.

Comment: Can you show me the exact php you used that gave you the error?

Also, have you tried just typing "echo $cat1;" somewhere on that page to make sure the value is set?

Comment: Yes I tried echoing $cat1 and I am getting the value